# Git: revert merge commit, but save save subsequent commits(after removed merge commit)

Tags: git

A two weeks ago branch 'branch-one'(that was created a two monts ago and contained a lot of old code) merged into 'master' and this commit has name 'commit123'. After merging team worked and made a lot of commits. Need to remove this merge, but save subsequent commits.

I see solution: revert merge commit, after add by cherry-pick subsequent commits, but this is long solution.

Does anyone can suggest much optimistic and short solution?

Answer (score 2):

**If** you have no problem rewriting history, get rid of the merge in history and replay history after it. Let's call that revision **merge-rev**

```
git checkout merge-rev~1 # right before the revision you want to get rid of
git cherry-pick merge-rev..master # linear history between merge and master (not including the merge you want to get rid). Adjust if the branch is not master
# if you like the results
git branch -f master
git push -f some-remote master # if you need to push somewhere to replace the old branch
```

This is assuming history is linear after the merge you want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout commit123 # the merge revision you want to get rid of
$ git reset --soft <the-commit-on-master-before-the-merge>
$ git commit -m 'squashed commit123'
$ git checkout origin/master
$ git revert <squashed-commit123>
```

The squashed commit has the same content as the merge, but is easier to revert on master.

Comment: Not what I would do (I would definitely rewrite history) but still a nice trick to get the content of the merge squashed into a single revision. Gotta love `git reset --soft`